# AgmCoreModule.forRoot returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument Angular 14

Tags: angular, agm

I have upgraded to Angular 14 and I am getting the following error:

> Error in turbo_modules/@agm/core@1.1.0/core.module.d.ts (29:79)
>
> AgmCoreModule.forRoot returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument. Please add a generic type argument to the ModuleWithProviders type. If this occurrence is in library code you don't control, please contact the library authors.
> AgmCoreModule.forRoot returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument. Please add a generic type argument to the ModuleWithProviders type. If this occurrence is in library code you don't control, please contact the library authors.

Here is Link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-slqupb?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Can you please have a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/sebholstein/angular-google-maps/issues/1794)?

Comment: npm i @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9nhc3g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is resolved by:

- As per  @cfprabhu's comment i have updated `@agm/core 3.0.0-beta.0` and
- Installed plugin `@types/googlemaps 3.43.3`

Here is working demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-slqupb?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

To get your build to work you have to have these dependancies in your package.json:

```
"@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0"
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.12",
```

[image]

but since **@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0** is not compatible with angular 14:

warning ">@agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/common@^9.1.0||^10.0.0".

warning " > @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0" has incorrect peer dependency
"@angular/core@^9.1.0 ||^10.0.0".

it is better to go with a library that is compatible with angular 14:

[@angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete)

Comment: you're right ^3.0.0-beta.0 is not compatible with angular 14

Comment: AGM Working fine But the issue comes when I use `<agm-marker-spider>`